# Oracle WHERE Clause/Searching

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner to oracle. In recent search I've seen `WHERE N-1,3-2` ..so on.

How does it work in searching data?

This is my code attemtp so far:

```
SELECT name, salary 
FROM #Employee e1
WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM #Employee e2
             WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So that we can better understand what you are trying to do here in your `WHERE` clause, could you please add sample data. You can use a site like [https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to format it for pasting in your question edit. Also please add desired results and an explanation about what you are trying to filter for here. For questions about [why we ask for this you can read here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Presumably, you want `rank()` or `row_number()`.  You should explain the *problem* you want to solve along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry Sir,Imnew to this site andi dont know what add an what not.Ive jsut got to knew from your message.From next question onwards i will keep will complte data..thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a classic( and pretty old ) SQL query to get nth highest salary. I assume It is no longer used( I haven't seen ) in any production codes, but could be a favourite question among the interviewers.

The N you are referring to is not a column or some unknown entity but a placeholder which should translate to a valid integer or bind argument in the working query. It is a **correlated subquery**, a subquery that is evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query. The way it works is that it takes a count of distinct list of salary values from employees that have a salary greater than each one of employees coming from the outer query and restricts the result where that count is equal to N-1.Which means you get those rows with nth highest salaries.

A more commonly used way to do this would be to use analytic function `dense_rank()` ( or `rank` depending on your need ). Read the documentation for these functions in case you aren't aware of them.

```
SELECT first_name,
       salary
FROM (
     SELECT e.*,
            dense_rank() OVER(
                 ORDER BY salary desc
            ) rn
     FROM employees e
)
WHERE rn = 6; -- ( n = 6 )
```

In Oracle 12c and higher versions, even though the above query works, a handy option to use is the `FETCH..FIRST` syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES; --n=6
```

Comment: Thank you sir ..It really helped